# Apollo/GraphQL: Field Type to Use for Timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, apollostack

I'm storing a value to a postgres field that is of type `timestamp with time zone`. I was defining the field as an int in my Apollo schema, but I'm getting this error message in the resolver:

> column "apptDateTime" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type integer

Looking up [GraphQL data types](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/), I don't yet see any type that is cited as corresponding to a field of type timestamp.

What's the correct field type to use in the Apollo schema for a field that is of type timestamp in the database?

Comment: Checkout the section on the date scalar: 
http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types
Probably best to define a custom scalar.

Comment: I’m reading up on dates and Apollo, and I note that as Tally posts, it is required to add custom code for this purpose. I found documentation here:

http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/scalars.html#Date-as-a-scalar

The docs define the resolver map, but don’t appear to show how to include the resolver map in your schema and/or other resolvers.

Can someone provide or link to an example of how to reference a resolver map from your other Apollo resolvers?

Comment: this is how it was done for json: https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my mutation working that includes a field of type Timestamp with Time Zone.  I did it by changing the schema for my apptDateTime field from Int to String, and passing in an ISO string. Sequelize and Postgres took care of changing it into a field of type Timestamp with Time Zone.

**Update 2021:**

Here's what I'm using these days.

Sequelize:

```
  timeOfNonce: {type: Sequelize.DATE}
```

Schema:

```
 scalar DATETIME
 .....
 timeOfNonce: DATETIME
```

These days I let Sequelize define my SQL tables via:

```
const deleteAllData_fromThisModel = false;
const alterThisTableToMatchDBConnectorsModel = true;

myDataModel.sync({force: deleteAllData_fromThisModel, 
                  alter: alterThisTableToMatchDBConnectorsModel}).then(err => {
    console.log('myDataModel has been synced')
}).catch(err => {
    throw err
});
```

Comment: can you show something of your code? did you not need :  require('pg').types.setTypeParser(1114, function(stringValue) {
  return new Date(stringValue + "+0000");
  // e.g., UTC offset. Use any offset that you would like.
});

Answer (score 3):

I find this way to work with input in forms, needed convert from client (input form) to the server, and from the server to  client (input form)

Graphql:

```
    updatedAt: String
```

Sequelize:

```
    updatedAt: {  type: Sequelize.DATE },
```

Postgresql:

```
    "createdAt" timestamp(6) with time zone DEFAULT now(),
```

Value transform to the  Server:

```
  value  = dateToISO(value);
```

Value transform to the  Client:

```
  if ( isNil(value) ) {
    value = '';
  } else {
    value  =  value.toLocaleDateString() +' '+ value.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
```

the helpers:

```
let dateToISO = function (dateString) {
  if (!dateString) {
    return null;
  }
  let p = dateString.split(/\D/g);
  /* It's up your date on input in this case come from DD-MM-YYYY
    for MM-DD-YYY use: return [p[1], p[2], p[0]].join('-'); */
  return [p[2], p[1], p[0]].join('-'); 

};
```